# what is best way to recursive update mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, hierarchical-data

im not good at php and mysql but i know some,,
my problem is that i want to update an 2 million row (in the future, but for now i only have around few data).

## 1

i have this table:

```
ID   BAnumber  DateEntry    Parent   Side  LastA  LastB
1   10001    01-01-2018                                             03-02-2018
2   10002    01-13-2018        9055       B
3   10003    01-15-2018       10001      A  03-02-2018
4   10004    01-20-2018       10002      B
5   10005    02-05-2018       10003      A  03-02-2018
6   10006    03-02-2018       10005      A
```

i will insert row 7

```
7   10008    03-20-2018       10005      B
```

row 7 is connected to the Parent 10005 in its Side B while row 6 is connected in Side A,

after insert row 7, i want to update its parent (10005) Last Day (Side B) to the DateEntry of the newly created,
and update the parent of 10005 (parent 10003 sideA) the LastA with the same date.
this goes over and over until the first data has no parent

```
ID   BAnumber  DateEntry    Parent   Side  LastA  LastB
1   10001    01-01-2018                                             03-23-2018
2   10002    01-13-2018        9055       A
3   10003    01-15-2018       10001      B    03-23-2018
4   10004    01-20-2018       10002      B
5   10005    02-05-2018       10003      A    03-02-2018  03-23-2018
6   10006    03-02-2018       10005      A
7   10008    03-23-2018       10005      B
```

i can do it by php:

```
1. insert row 7,
2. search parent and side of row 7
3. update row 5
4. search parent and side of row 5
5. update row 3
6. search parent and side of row 3
7. update row 1
```

this will have too many sql query inside a loop, and this can be fine in small amount of data, but how to optimize it in large data?

my code is working but i want to optimize only for larger data.

sorry i dont know how to post table and code here using mobile..

## 2

another question,,
i didnt really used the ID column, it is PK,,
should i delete it and make BANumber the primary key?
but BAnumber should not be autoincrement.

is it better that way?

Comment: Take a look at these links: [Optimizing INSERT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-optimization.html), [Optimizing UPDATE Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update-optimization.html), [Optimizing SELECT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-optimization.html). This is as good as it gets. You could also load everything into a humongous array, process everything in PHP and then use UPDATE statements only by iterating through the array, but that would be weird too. In any case, 2M rows of data will take a very long time to process.

Comment: thank you, i found that connecting has the hightes amount of time used.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct.

Why? Production versions of MySQL lack the ability to perform hierarchical queries (for example, SELECT  data WHERE row *is ancestor of* nnnnn). MySQL doesn't have a built-in `WHERE P is-ancestor-of C` operation, only the `WHERE P is-parent-of C` operation implemented by `WHERE P.BANumber = C.parent`.

So, you need to use queries in a loop to do your operation. You will need to run your query once for each level of ancestry.  If some of your data rows contain a million levels of ancestry you will run your loop a million times.  That's a lot of times to run a loop.  (Most hierarchical representations, such as bills of materials--widget: case: screw--don't have nearly that many levels of ancestry. Ten levels is a lot in real-world data.)

You may want to use a transaction or table lock so simultaneous attempted updates to a particular chain of ancestry don't cause confusion.

SQL Server, recent versions of MariaDB, and PostgreSQL (among others) implement hierarchical queries using recursive common table expressions (which you can look up). Oracle uses a specialized `START WITH ... CONNECT BY` query syntax for this.

But if your data has a great many levels of ancestry, I strongly suggest you try to use another way of representing it.

As to your question about using your unique real-world `BANumber` identifier as a primary key, rather than an autoicremented integer:  yes.

Comment: do you mean i can only update the parent of parent of parent nnnnn using a loop of php and not with sql queries? do you have any idea on how long should i update an entire 1million data using this method? (i only have few hundreds for now). should it take, 1 minute?

Comment: should i search first the ancestry and then save to a temporary table then update them?

Comment: Using an extra table to hold your ancestry information is not a *bad* idea. Whether it is a *good* idea depends on the details of your real-world requirements. When you do data modeling (designing your tables) you match your real-world requirements. I don't want to offer advice on that because I know nothing about what you're modeling.